# Code Warrior. Processor Expert error

Tags: embedded, usb, arm, codewarrior

I`ve tried to setup USB CDC DEVICE on Kinetics KL25 via processor expert in CW. And got this:
[image]

And i cannot change value in that fields. Maybe trouble in other things. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late but I think you will be able to change the fields using "Advanced Mode".